# How to custom page margin in google docs api?

Tags: node.js, google-docs-api, google-apis-explorer

I try to custom my page size and margin but it doesn't working.
I had try to used the auto API in the site but the result still not change the margin.
Is there any change in the google docs api?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that `documentStyle` and `content` cannot be set with the method of documents.create. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123897235) I confirmed that this has still not been modified. So as the current workaround, how about the following flow?

#### Flow:

1. Create new Document using the method of `documents.create`. In this case, the title can be set.
2. Set `updateDocumentStyle` using the method of `documents.batchUpdate`.

   - From your question, the request body for documents.batchUpdate is as follows.

     ```
     {
       "requests": [
         {
           "updateDocumentStyle": {
             "documentStyle": {
               "marginTop": {
                 "magnitude": 100,
                 "unit": "PT"
               },
               "marginLeft": {
                 "magnitude": 500,
                 "unit": "PT"
               }
             },
             "fields": "marginTop,marginLeft"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
     ```

#### References:

- [Method: documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.