# python program horizontal stapled booklet integration in google doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, google-docs-api

I have a Google doc with around 60 pages, it's in vertical scrolling format. I am thinking of converting this doc into another doc that is printable horizontally such that it can be stapled in the middle.

```
mypage_content_vertical = [
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
]
```

horizontal output needs to be:

```
page 1: 
 front:
   first-half: page 2(start to center)
   second-half: page 15(center to end)
 rear:
   first-half: page 16(start to center)
   second-half: page 1(center to end)

page 2:
 front:
   first-half: page 4(start to center)
   second-half: page 13(center to end)
 rear:
   first-half: page 14(start to center)
   second-half: page 3(center to end)
....
```

I can write the Python program that would do this, but I am not sure how I can integrate it into Google Docs, as manually updating the doc can be error-prone and tedious.

The Google doc is in a horizontal layout with Format->Columns set to `2 parts split in the middle`

Any other tools or methods that can transform the vertical pages into horizontal ones such that they can be stapled in the middle of the horizontal page would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, this feature is not available in Google Docs. This seems to be a printing feature. However, if you insist on this feature, you may file a feature request through [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211163).

Comment: @PatrickdC thanks for the suggestion, do you know any other tools similar to Google docs that supports this out of the box?

Answer (score -1):

You might use the Google Docs API. You might have to start by installing the client library for Python. The details are at https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/libraries#python

You must get familiar with the [document structure](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure). There general document settings like page margin are handled with [DocumentStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#DocumentStyle). In order to handle different margins for different parts of your document, you will have to insert sections and handle section styles.

Related

- [How to custom page margin in google docs api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60145800/1595451)
- [Styling Sections and Bulleted Lists via Google Docs API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73993468/1595451)
- [How to change Google Docs specific section margins using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75865222/1595451)